# How to verify an arrest in Russia?

Tags: arrest, cryptocurrency, sanctions, russia

Assume the media reports that a particular individual has been arrested by Russian police. Others reports deny this. Is there any authoritative legal mechanism for ascertaining the true situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many Western sources claim that Russia is a dictatorship and that the Russian government routinely breaks Russian domestic laws as well as international ones. Many Russian sources disagree, and call this Western propaganda. If you are in the West, you are free to *believe* either the Western or the Russian side, but you cannot *know* the truth.

If you do *believe* that Russian agencies [poisoned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisoning_of_Alexei_Navalny) [opponents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisoning_of_Sergei_and_Yulia_Skripal), would you *believe* any claim that they do not hold an individual in detention? The denial might even remain questionable after the person [reappears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disappearance_of_Peng_Shuai) in public.

So it comes down to the usual questions:

- Who is reporting what? Do they have a track record of correct investigative reporting?
- What sources are given? Do the sources sound credible? (Of course news media often refuses to name sources to protect them. Back to the bullet point above.)
- Does the report claim to have multiple sources?